# Installing require-dev dependencies from core/composer.json

Tags: 8, composer

I understand the [composer-merge-plugin](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin) allows the Drupal root composer.json file to load core/composer.json on runtime. I also understand `require-dev` will only pull dependencies for the root composer.json file (see [this link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev)).

How can I force one/all core/composer.json dependencies (including the required-dev ones) to be pulled if I want without hacking the root composer.json file e.g. with a `composer require vendor/package`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Composer will install also the development requirements, if you don't use the `--no-dev` option.
I ran  `composer create-project drupal/drupal test 8.3.*@dev`, and in the output of the command I could see the following:

> Installing drupal/drupal (8.3.x-dev
>   8a84ec5556f354861f1ddc5d7a80081b91ca42df)
>     - Installing drupal/drupal (8.3.x-dev 8a84ec5)
>   Cloning 8a84ec5556 from cache
>   Created project in test
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>   Package operations: 76 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
>
> [Omissis]
>
> - Installing drupal/coder (8.2.11) Downloading: 100%
> - Installing phpunit/phpunit (4.8.28) Downloading: 100%

If you downloaded the archived release for example from https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.2.7, which doesn't include the development requirements, you need to run `composer update` from the directory containing core and composer.json.
I tested `composer update --dev` after removing the vendor directory from the test directory created from the previous command, and I got this output:

> You are using the deprecated option "dev". Dev packages are installed by default now.
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Package operations: 76 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

Comment: My issue with this is I'm currently pulling from a `git clone` and installing via `drush site-install` as there's no way that I know of we can install the tip of 8.4.x (aka chase HEAD) with `create-project`. But regardless, your answer does provide an interesting workaround to the original issue. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `composer create-project drupal/drupal test 8.4.*@dev` for Drupal 8.4.x.

Comment: I was more talking about something like `composer create-project drupal/drupal test 8.4.*@dev#<commithash>` - Filed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872173/pull-latest-commit-with-composer-create-project accordingly.